# IAP: How to save the effect of the purchase

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, iad

In my app, I have an IAP that removes iAd banner from the screen bottom. I achieve this through the following code.

```
func removeAds() {
    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "productID is here")
    purchaseButton.alpha = 0.0
    self.canDisplayBannerAds = false
    print("iAd removed and default value set")
    defaults.synchronize()
    }
}
```

I also have this code in my other view controllers

```
 let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    let showAds = defaults.boolForKey("productID is here")
    if (showAds) {
        // User purchsed IAP
        // Lets remove ads
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = false
        print("iAd removed")
    } else {
        // IAP not purchased
        // Lets show some ads
        self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
        print("Showing iAd")
    }
```

When I purchase with a test user, it is successful and the ad is removed from that view controller. However, as soon as I leave the view from which I purchased from, and go back, the ad reappears. My purchase is of a non-consumable type.

My question is how to I make this permanent

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the code that you have shown in your second block?  If it is in `viewDidLoad` then it won't be executed when you return to a view controller that was loaded before purchase.  Try it in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: Yes its in viewdidload, tried it in viewwillappear but no ad appears, just the space for it

Comment: You need to adjust your constraints or otherwise manipulate your layout if you aren't displaying the banner view.  Also are you aware that iAd is being discontinued in a few months?

Comment: Like entirely discontinued? I thought it was just the developers ability to display your own ads on other devices?

Comment: According to this http://9to5mac.com/2016/01/15/apple-will-discontinue-iad-app-network-for-developers-on-june-30th/ it is the whole thing but I can't find that confirmed anywhere else

Comment: So this http://www.engadget.com/2016/01/15/apple-iad-shutdown-june-30th/ says it is just the app network.  Confusing

Comment: hmm, thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 2):

The way you named the bool is confusing, you should maybe call it

```
let removedAds = ....
```

instead of

```
 let showAds = ...
```

If you call this code in your viewControllers right at launch I dont see why it wouldnt work.

Are you sure you haven't made a typo with the Keys for the localDefaults?
You should use a struct

```
struct Key {
    static let key = "Key1"
}
```

or

```
struct ProductID {
    static let removedAds = "Your removed ads product ID"
}
```

if you are not already doing so to avoid typos.

Is there another line of

```
self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
```

that you forgot to delete?

Maybe post some more code of your view controllers so we can get some more idea of whats happening.

As a side note you don't have to call

```
 defaults.synchronize()
```

anymore since iOS 8, so you should delete that line.